# Trying to import class from a module in the same package by a string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a market robot, which can support different markets. 
Currently it is hardcoded into the code, and i want to change that.
In my src folder, i have a main.py that imports markets.
Markets is a package that looks like this

```
markets/
    __init__.py
    market_template.py
    market1.py
    market2.py
```

What i have done is added a load and a autoload function in my **init**.py which looks like this

```
logging.getLogger(__name__)
slaves = {}

def autoload():
    for market in settings.conf["Markets"]:
        load(market)

def load(market):
    print("Starting {} interface".format(market))
    slaves[market].start()

autoload()
```

This part works great, so now to the real problem.

I want to import the specified markets module and its class inside (Which has the same name as the module)
This is easily made by a 'from .market1 import market1', but that little dot which resembles that it's in the same package makes everything hell.
I have tried multiple things, and two of them are

```
from . import *
eval('market1')
```

and

```
module = __import__("." + market)
my_class = getattr(module, market)
```

But neither of these are able to access anything within the same package by some reason...
Thanks

Comment: What happens with your second attempt?

Comment: simply 'ImportError: No module named .market1' from the __import__()

Comment: Take a look at [`importlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)

Comment: I did that before, but did not know how to do it. First, i tried 'import_module(market)', but that wasn't in the local package. So then i tried 'import_module(str("." + market))', which gave me "TypeError: relative imports require the 'package' argument".
And i have absolutely no idea what to use as the package argument because it's in itselves package?

Comment: Did you try providing a `package` argument (`package='markets'`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from importlib import import_module
import_module(str("." + market), 'market')
```

Thanks to blender in the comment field under my question